# Append/Copy a dataframe with multiple columns headers to existing excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy/append a dataframe with multiple column headers(similar to the one below) to an existing excel sheet starting from a particular cell `AA2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sub1': [np.nan,'E',np.nan,'S'],
                   'sub2': [np.nan,'D',np.nan,'A']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sub1': [np.nan,'D',np.nan,'S'],
                    'sub2': [np.nan,'C',np.nan,'S']})

df = pd.concat({'Af':df1, 'Dp':df2}, axis=1)

df
```

I'm thinking of a solution to export this dataframe to an excel starting in that particular cell and use openpyxl to copy the data from one to another - column by column... but not sure if that is the correct approach. any ideas?!

(the excel sheet that I'm working with has formatting and can't make it into a dataframe and use merge)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success manipulating Excel files in the past with xlsxwriter (you will need to pip install this as a dependency first - although it does not need to be explicitly imported).

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Load your file here instead
file_bytes = io.BytesIO()

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_bytes, engine = 'xlsxwriter') as writer:

  # Write a DataFrame to Excel into specific cells
  pd.DataFrame().to_excel(
    writer,
    sheet_name = 'test_sheet',
    startrow = 10, startcol = 5,
    index = False
  )
  # Note: You can repeat any of these operations within the context manager
  # and keep adding stuff...


  # Add some text to cells as well:
  writer.sheets['test_sheet'].write('A1', 'Your text goes here')

file_bytes.seek(0)
# Then write your bytes to a file...
# Overwriting it in your case?
```

**Bonus**:
You can add plots too - just write them to a BytesIO object and then call `<your_image_bytes>.seek(0)` and then use in `insert_image()` function.

```
  ... # still inside ExcelWriter context manager
  
  plot_bytes = io.BytesIO()
  
  # Create plot in matplotlib here

  plt.savefig(plot_bytes, format='png') # Instead of plt.show()
    plot_bytes.seek(0)

  writer.sheets['test_sheet'].insert_image(
    5, # Row start
    5, # Col start
    'some_image_name.png',
    options = {'image_data': plot_bytes}
  )
```

The full documentation is really helpful too:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: This is great but this overwrites the data on the present excel sheet. I would prefer to add the dataframe in addition to the existing data.  Lets say I've a sheet with data from A2:G8, I'm trying to add the dataframe in that sheet starting from H2 without overwriting the existing data. And since the sheet comes with cell formatting, using a dataframe will remove that. Do you have any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: @ArunakiriVenkatachalam Check out that link to the documentation at the bottom, there's some stuff about formatting in there